# Using if statement to compare multiple objects java

Tags: java

I am issuing cars for a car rental class using the driving licence and using the car type as input parameters to my method. as I am using an interface, I have to issue big and small cars depending on the driver's age and the time they have had the licence. for ex: for a big car, he needs to be at least 23 and to have 4 years driving experience. I am stuck on how to check the type of car the driver will be issued and the subsequent age checks. My code is a little messy but I could really use some help as I can't logically advance. below is my method.

```
public CarInterface issueCar(DrivingLicence aLicence, CarType typeOfCar) {
    final boolean isLicenceFull = drivingLicence.getLicenceStatus();

     final Optional<CarInterface> optionalCar = availableCars.stream()
           .filter(car -> typeOfCar == car.getType())
           .findAny();

     final CarInterface car = optionalCar.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("All cars of type " + typeOfCar + " have been rented"));
        if(aLicence.getLicenceStatus() ==true){
            if(!rentals.containsKey(aLicence)){
                if(typeOfCar.equals(optionalCar)){


                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: means you want to add all conditions in one if ,OR you want to add multipal validations one by one .

Comment: I want multiple validation one by one

Comment: you can do this by using if else .

Comment: ok, thanks, so how would you syntactically choose between small and big cars?. I can't seem to find a path to that

Comment: if your one condition is depend on first condition then you may put all condition together in one if by using **&&** operator.

Comment: Thanks, however I probably,need rephrase my question and focus on what I would do after the line "else if(typeOfCar.equals(optionalCar)){". As small and big cars have a class of their own, what would you do to create an instance of each in which you would check their age and so on? in my code I am finding it hard to relate optionCar to either big or small car options

Comment: also adding that I created an enum CarType containing BIG and SMALL as options

Comment: you may use switch case  for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `if` and `else` .

```
public CarInterface issueCar(DrivingLicence aLicence, CarType typeOfCar) {
        final boolean isLicenceFull = drivingLicence.getLicenceStatus();

        final Optional<CarInterface> optionalCar = availableCars.stream()
                .filter(car -> typeOfCar == car.getType())
                .findAny();

        final CarInterface car = optionalCar.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("All cars of type " + typeOfCar + " have been rented"));
        if(aLicence.getLicenceStatus() ==true){
            if(!rentals.containsKey(aLicence)){

            }else if(typeOfCar.equals(optionalCar)){

            }
        }
}
```

**If...else if...else Statement**

> An if statement can be followed by an optional else if...else
>   statement, which is very useful to test various conditions using
>   single if...else if statement.
>
> When using if...else if..else statements, there are few points to keep
>   in mind −
>
> An if can have zero or one else's and it must come after any else
>   if's.
>
> An if can have zero to many else if's and they must come before the
>   else.
>
> Once an else if succeeds, none of the remaining else if's or else's
>   will be tested.

Answer (score 0):

If you will only issue a big car if both conditions apply then you will need something like this:

```
 if(driver.getAge() > 23 && license.getPeriod() > 4) {
     // issue a big car
 } else {
    // issue a small car
 }
```